# Jquery find and hasAttr

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I try to find in a `div`, all the tables that have an `id`.
kind of:

```
var tables = $('#m2').find('table').hasAttr('id');
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.filter()` method to filter all method which has id set

```
$('#m2').find('table').filter(function(index){
    if($(this).hasAttr('id')) return this;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using jquery map function.

```
var tables = $('#m2').find('table').map(function(i,e) {
      if ($(e).hasAttr("id")) return this;
      return null;
}).get();
```